# How to get and set / access and modify a global variable between components

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface

I'm new to Angular, currently using Angular 5 Cli with VS Code. I have 2x components (Comp1 & Comp2) that need to access the same variable which is ultimately a string. This variable is rendered in the 3rd Component's (Comp 3) View/HTML template.

What's the best way to access this? 
Example files below:

Comp3.html

```
<a routerLink="/{{modeName | lowercase}}" class="mode"><span class="icon {{modeName | lowercase}}"></span><span>{{modeName}}</span></a>
```

Comp3.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LowerCasePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
selector: 'pm-nav-button',
templateUrl: './comp3.component.html'
})

export class Comp3 {

constructor() {}

modeName: string;


}
```

Comp2.ts & Comp1.ts - (these are configured based on Angular Routing whichever view loads it'll set 'Grid' mode or 'List' mode)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LowerCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Comp3 } from './comp3-component';

@Component({
selector: 'content-two',
templateUrl: './comp3.component.html'
})

export class Comp2 implements OnInit {

constructor(private _comp3: Comp3) {}


ngOnInit(): void {
    this._Comp3.modeName = 'Grid';
}



}
```

However, it all compiles fine with no errors, but I'm not seeing 'Grid' binded to the template's bindings (interpolation). I think I'm setting the the variable after the template has rendered, even though I'm setting it within ngOnInit. I want to be able to access, check and set this variable from other components. How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should  use a shared service.

You can try following code snippet.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("list");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)

  }
}
```

//Comp1

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../shared.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp1.component.css']
})
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {

   message:string;
  constructor(private data: SharedService) {

   }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
    console.log(this.message);
  }

}
```

//Comp2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../shared.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp2',
  templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp2.component.css']
})
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {

    message:string;
  constructor(private data: SharedService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
    console.log(this.message);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I can't seem to get it to work.
Within Comp1/Comp2 how can I then update message? - It's always being forced to 'list' from your example.
I've tried referencing the changeMessage function but nothing happens or updates in the bindings. Although I can see it happening in the console. Just not in the bindings/template.

Comment: Check out this demo link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4djyiy?embed=1&file=app/comp1/comp1.component.ts

Comment: Thanks Santosh - after a playing about with the code I now understand it and can adapt it to fit within my app.